# link foreing key to a foreign key in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, create-table

```
Create table StoreManagers
(ID INT ,
OfficeNumber nchar(8),
Bonus INT,
FOREIGN KEY (ID) references Employees(ID)
);

Create table Stores
(ID INT,
ManagerID INT  ,
Address nvarchar(100),
Phone nchar(8),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) references StoreManagers(ID)
);
```

How to link a foreign key to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent looks ok. The only problem is that you did not declare the primary key of table `StoreManager` - which should be `ID` - as a result, you cannot have a foreign key referencing this column.

This works fine (assuming, of course, that you have a table `Employees`, whose primary key is `ID`):

```
CREATE TABLE StoreManagers(
    ID INT,
    OfficeNumber nchar(8),
    Bonus INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) references Employees(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Stores (
    ID INT,
    ManagerID INT,
    Address nvarchar(100),
    Phone nchar(8),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) references StoreManagers(ID)
);
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc4a925fa2a01b093cc4679bbf846f98)**